# set badge on tabbar item when notification received

Tags: ios, push-notification, xcode5, uitabbarcontroller, badge

I tried to set badgeValue for `UITabBarItem` when push notification is received.I am using this code. Here the `UITabBarController` is not a rootViewController. I tried the same thing in resign active method but there also its not working.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

  UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarController"] ;
  [[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setBadgeValue:@"1"];

}
```

Comment: You need to study the object management and creation. You are trying to set badge on `UITabBarItem` of a new `UITabBarController` instantiated by you from storyboard. Also do read the `NSNotification`. It will help you to understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you can use NSNotificationCenter to post notification when you received a remoteNotification

In your `UITabBarController` initialize method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myNotificationReceived:) name:@"pushNotification" object:nil];
```

And
In `myNotificationReceived:`

```
[[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setBadgeValue:@"1"];
```

When you receive a remote notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

In this way, you can get whole RemoteNotification information

Comment: when app is in foreground state user can be in any screen ,to use notification center,i need to add observer for all the screens,can i achieve this without observers.

Comment: You just add observer to UITabbarController,you can access any viewcontroller in UITabbarController by using self.viewControllers.This will return an array of viewController in UITabbarController.

Comment: Thanks ,should i subclass uiTabBarController for receiving notification.